# Event loop is closed discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: screenshot]
For some reason I can't call my commands. `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`. I want to learn how to create bots for discord on Python!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "TOKEN-HERE"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title="Title",description ="This is a description",color=0x20B2AA)
    em.set_footer(text='This is a footer.')
    em.set_image(url='')
    em.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/823480191493210113/886011319688527892/Screenshot_808.png')
    em.set_author(name='Author Name', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/823480191493210113/886011319688527892/Screenshot_808.png')
    em.add_field(name='Field Name', value='Field Value', inline=False)
    em.add_field(name='Field Name', value='Field Value', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name='Field Name', value='Field Value', inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@client.command()
async def asnwer(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hi !")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000020AAF885040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000020AAF885040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't enable `Intents`. Remember to do it both in code and on your bot's dashboard on the Discord developers site if you need privileged intents enabled. This includes things like wanting access to the members in a Guild, etc.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

More info here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Also you just leaked your bot token, generate a new one.

Comment: What does that have to do with the error?

Comment: @WasiMaster If your bot has no intents enabled it can crash automatically, this error is usually raised when `client.close()` is called, but OP didn't do that so that's not the issue here. OP didn't provide any traceback at all, and `PrivilegedIntentsRequired` is an exception that causes this error message when raised internally.

Comment: I did it, but anyway i have the same error

Comment: @WitalikZarscikov can you provide the actual traceback of the error in your post instead of just the message? That way we can see where it comes from.

Comment: Preferably copy-paste it in instead of putting it in an image in the future. Half of it is crossed out as well which doesn't really help the case.

Comment: @WitalikZarscikov I just ran it through my own bot and it works just fine, only error I imagine you could get is your bot token being invalid. Are you sure you have the right one? You can generate a new one on your developer console, and make sure to replace it in your code afterwards.

Comment: I dont know why, but i created a new bot and anyway when i stopped my bot I'm getting the same error...

Comment: But only commands do not run, events are good

Comment: @stijndcl `PrivilegedIntentsRequired` would raise it if OP had passed intents that were not enabled in the dev portal, OP did not pass any intents so that would not be raised

Comment: @WitalikZarscikov your error screenshot is absolutely useless. **Copy and paste** the error traceback into your question. If you want to replace your username with XXX, that's fine, but leave everything else. That's important information you're hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that your bot is running? I'm getting this error everytime I stop my bot.